# Is it bad practice to use print (rather than echo) so I can use headers() later?

Tags: php

Just like the question states, earlier today I solved a bug in my code by replacing a javascript redirect with a php redirect:

```
header('Location: index.php')
```

The only way I could accomplish this was by replacing every `echo` in my code with `print`. By doing this I was allowed to use the `header()` call.

I'm interested to know if this is bad practice, and if so, why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are echo and print different in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234241/how-are-echo-and-print-different-in-php)

Comment: The only difference, echo returns a void and print returns a bool.

Comment: @Xorifelse: actually `print` returns `int`, specifically number 1, always.

Comment: @JiriHrazdil While you are technically correct, how is it in "PHP" terms different from a bool? Do you do `if(print("") == 1)` or do you evaluate it as a bool by leaving out the `== 1`?.

Comment: That should not have made a difference. `The only difference to print is that echo accepts an argument list.` -http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php both should cause output which makes the `header` not thrown. How about adding the code to the question so we can see what you are doing?

Comment: There's no way that replacing `echo` with `print` could prevent the "Headers already sent" problem. Any form of output before `header()` causes that, it doesn't matter how it's done. You must have changed something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between `echo` and `print` in this case.

Maybe you can try [`ob_clean`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php) to clear your php output buffer before you use `header` to send a redirect header